# Floating a div containing a picture left in a nested div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to float a picture left in the snippet below (a table cell). There is no CSS applied other than that shown below - I have tried everything I can think of, to no avail. I am displaying the page in FF.

```
    <tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            <div style="width:60%; float left;">
                <div>
                    <div><h4 style="margin:0px 0px;">Hello</h4> <strong>World!</strong></div>
                    <div>Line 1</div>
                    <div>Line 2</div>
                    <div>Line 3</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Line 4</div>
                    <div>Line 5</div>
                </div>
                <!-- no effect, so commented out 
                <div style="clear:both; height: 1px;"></div> -->
            </div>
            <!-- I want this next div floated right as instructed in the CSS - but it has no effect! :/ -->                    
            <div style="width:35%; float right;">
                <a href="<?php echo $row['page_link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['photo_link']; ?>" /></a>
            </div>
            <!-- no effect, so commented out 
            <div style="clear:both; height: 1px;"></div> -->
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: next time use a css validator to check for this kind of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <div style="width:35%; float right;">
                                ^-- missing :
```

Without the `:`, you've just got a CSS syntax error and the style rule is ignored.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that... I thought I was going mad!. Incidentally, do you know why clear:both is often used in nested div?. Sometimes it seems to have an effect, other times it dosen't - I never really figured out when to use clear:both (optionally with a height), in nested divs - can you (or anyone else) shine some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a colon:

```
<div style="width:60%; float:left;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your float:right command is wrong. You don't have a colon. Also, the floated div should be moved in the code above the items it's going to float next to. It should look like:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            <!-- ABOVE AND WITH A COLON! :/ -->                    
            <div style="width:35%; float:right;">
                <a href="<?php echo $row['page_link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['photo_link']; ?>" /></a>
            </div>

            <div style="width:60%; float left;">
                <div>
                    <div><h4 style="margin:0px 0px;">Hello</h4> <strong>World!</strong></div>
                    <div>Line 1</div>
                    <div>Line 2</div>
                    <div>Line 3</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Line 4</div>
                    <div>Line 5</div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div style="clear:both; height: 1px;"></div> -->
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
```